# ajax process control

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, process

Is there any builtin control in ajax to show process indicator. Like when i press copy button in my page one popup shuold come and show a small process animation gif.

is it possible in ajax using c#?

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I need to do this in my web site and I've found this page. Check this out and see if fits to your needs.

[http://mattberseth.com/blog/](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/05/aspnet_ajax_progress_bar_contr.html)

Cheers,